# python 3.7 install pygal and interrupt with non-reasonable errors

Tags: python

when try to install pygal following [Installing — pygal 2.0.0 documentation](http://www.pygal.org/en/stable/installing.html)

It report enormous errors

```
$ pip install pygal
Collecting pygal
  Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x7fd5777e1390>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 101] Network is unreachable')': /packages/5f/b7/201c9254ac0d2b8ffa3bb2d528d23a4130876d9ba90bc28e99633f323f17/pygal-2.4.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/5f/b7/201c9254ac0d2b8ffa3bb2d528d23a4130876d9ba90bc28e99633f323f17/pygal-2.4.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (127kB)
    24% |███████▊                        | 30kB 899bytes/s eta 0:01:48Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/me/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/urllib3/contrib/pyopenssl.py", line 294, in recv_into
    return self.connection.recv_into
```

I notice that

> pygal is available for python 2.7 and 3.2, 3.3, 3.4, 3.5 and pypy.

Does it mean pygal not support python3.6 or python3.7?

I am very confused with that?  why python3.* packages has such a dedicated distinctions among the minor versions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Intermittent HTTP error, likely due to flaky internet connection. Retrying will probably resolve the issue.

> Why python3.* packages has such a dedicated distinctions among the minor versions?

Usually devs mention each version which they have tested their module on. Also, in each release sometimes there are major changes which may break the module. For example in Python 3.7 async has been reserved as a keyword. I had a method named async in one of the module that I wrote, I had to rename it to be able to support Python 3.7.